# ASP.NET-MVC: Order of OnActionExecuted execution between controller and attributes

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

Does anyone know what the rules are for order of execution of `OnActionExecuted` in

1. An overridden `OnActionExecuted`
   method in the controller/base
   controller, and
2. An `OnActionExecuted`
   method in an Attribute/ActionFilter applied to
   the Action?

Is the order guaranteed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Overridden controller methods are always higher in the filter stack and will therefore get called first and order is guaranteed.